# Identify if Windows hosted on physical or Virtual machine? #Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, virtual-machine, virtualization

I am trying to find if windows os hosted on physical or virtual machine.

there is one snippet of powershell script available on the internet, to which I have added few more conditions to identify if the machine is hosted on cloud (then it is probably virtual machine).

```
function GetMachineType {
    $ComputerSystemInfo = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_ComputerSystem
    switch ($ComputerSystemInfo.Model) { 

        # Check for VMware Machine Type 
        "VMware Virtual Platform" { 
            Write-Output "This Machine is Virtual on VMware Virtual Platform."
            Break 
        } 

        # Check for Oracle VM Machine Type 
        "VirtualBox" { 
            Write-Output "This Machine is Virtual on Oracle VM Platform."
            Break 
        } 
        default { 

            switch ($ComputerSystemInfo.Manufacturer) {

                # Check for Xen VM Machine Type
                "Xen" {
                    Write-Output "This Machine is Virtual on Xen Platform"
                    Break
                }

                # Check for KVM VM Machine Type
                "QEMU" {
                    Write-Output "This Machine is Virtual on KVM Platform."
                    Break
                }
                # Check for Hyper-V Machine Type 
                "Microsoft Corporation" { 
                    if (get-service WindowsAzureGuestAgent -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) {
                        Write-Output "This Machine is Virtual on Azure Platform"
                    }
                    else {
                        Write-Output "This Machine is Virtual on Hyper-V Platform"
                    }
                    Break
                }
                # Check for Google Cloud Platform
                "Google" {
                    Write-Output "This Machine is Virtual on Google Cloud."
                    Break
                }

                # Check for AWS Cloud Platform
                default { 
                    if ((((Get-WmiObject -query "select uuid from Win32_ComputerSystemProduct" | Select-Object UUID).UUID).substring(0, 3) ) -match "EC2") {
                        Write-Output "This Machine is Virtual on AWS"
                    }
                    # Otherwise it is a physical Box 
                    else {
                        Write-Output "This Machine is Physical Platform"
                    }
                } 
            }                  
        } 
    } 

}
```

the below registry key will only provide information if the VM is on HYPER-V

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Virtual Machine\Guest\Parameters*

I want to know if there is any generic way to find out programatically if the windows OS is hosted on physical or virtual machine.

Comment: You may want to add `"Virtual Machine" { Write-Output "This Machine is Virtual on Hyper-V Platform."; break }` to the `$ComputerSystemInfo.Model` switch.

Comment: Here's a script that may help: https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Get-MachineType-VM-or-ff43f3a9

Comment: Hey @Theo , That was handled in default block of switch statement. but unfortunately that is not my question. :( . I need an alternative and Generic way to find out if the machine is physical or virtual as it has the dependency of all the virtualization providers available which are to be handled separately.

Comment: @Glenn That is pretty much similar script..

Comment: I know this isn't your question, but FYI: the GetMachineType function returns "This Machine is Virtual on Xen Platform" on an AWS EC2 instance; after determining the Manufacturer is "Xen," the function needs to check for the AWS Cloud Platform. If the AWS Cloud Platform check fails, it's Xen. If the AWS Cloud Program check passes, it's an EC2 instance.

Comment: "_available on the internet_" is unnecessarily vague, especially because the internet works because of links and you could have simply linked to the site where you copied the code from.

Answer (score 6):

```
    $IsVirtual=((Get-WmiObject win32_computersystem).model -eq 'VMware Virtual Platform' -or ((Get-WmiObject win32_computersystem).model -eq 'Virtual Machine'))
```

It will output $True or $False
Extend this with other virtual models / manufacturers in your estate

Comment: You'd also need to check for 'Parallels Virtual Platform' for example. Consequently, I'd use the following approach: `$IsVirtual = ((Get-WmiObject Win32_ComputerSystem).model).Contains("Virtual")`